# Mysql deadlock on simple parent-child tables

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, database-deadlocks

In my Spring Boot application I use JPA, Hibernate, JdbcTemplate. I found a really odd case when I'm doing a rather simple transaction. I tried many changes in my code, analyzed Mysql general logs many times, but I can't figure out where there problem is.

What I'm doing is:

1. create an AdjustmentOrder record (it's the header of the order)
2. create an AdjustmentOrderLine record (a line of the order)

in the same transaction. A simple thing I did million times, but this time I've a deadlock.

Adjustment order DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `adjustmentorder` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdByName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBySid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `lastModifiedByName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedBySid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `userInputTime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `headerText` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `number` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `numberSeries` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reasonForAdjustment` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OPEN',
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_gpc4efr5w060sqepkpi723blv` (`sid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_adjustmentorder_number` (`numberSeries`,`number`,`year`),
  KEY `idx_adjustmentorder_code` (`code`),
  KEY `idx_adjustmentorder_status` (`status`),
  KEY `FKqk839pyqdm2dpj8mb0biajb68` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKqk839pyqdm2dpj8mb0biajb68` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Adjustment order line DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `adjustmentorderline` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdByName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBySid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `lastModifiedByName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedBySid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `userInputTime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `adjustmentDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adjustmentPrice` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `errorMessage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inventoryAdjusted` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `itemGroup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `itemBarcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemCode` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `itemDescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `itemManufacturer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `itemSku` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `itemType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `itemVariantCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemVariantId` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if((`itemVariant_id` is not null),`itemVariant_id`,-(1))) VIRTUAL,
  `line` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `orderCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `processingDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `projectId` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if((`project_id` is not null),`project_id`,-(1))) VIRTUAL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OPEN',
  `stockPointInventory` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `transactionAmount` decimal(12,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`adjustmentPrice` * (`inventoryAdjusted` - `stockPointInventory`))) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `variance` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`inventoryAdjusted` - `stockPointInventory`)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `itemVariant_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_adjustmentorderline_orderid_line` (`order_id`,`line`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_gwqf9d02aa1b3o45ajtyav5al` (`sid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_adjustmentorderline_item_variant` (`order_id`,`store_id`,`itemType`,`item_id`,`projectId`,`itemVariantId`),
  KEY `idx_adjustmentorderline_product` (`itemType`,`item_id`,`itemCode`,`itemBarcode`),
  KEY `idx_adjustmentorderline_status` (`status`),
  KEY `idx_adjustmentorderline_line` (`line`),
  KEY `FK6etpb3q107v86wpud5viffwvm` (`itemVariant_id`),
  KEY `FK6ucq04dc2fvdp78wmdhtm3r7w` (`project_id`),
  KEY `FK9lsgaxlth3ws5vj6kkoxovhbm` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK6etpb3q107v86wpud5viffwvm` FOREIGN KEY (`itemVariant_id`) REFERENCES `productvariant` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK6ucq04dc2fvdp78wmdhtm3r7w` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK9lsgaxlth3ws5vj6kkoxovhbm` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKo4j5q73gdxcrrr9dg3t35mdq9` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `adjustmentorder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

For space reason I can't paste the entire Mysql's general log, but this is the result of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`: https://codeshare.io/5M7QLO

What I realized, is that removing the foreign key FKo4j5q73gdxcrrr9dg3t35mdq9 from adjustmentorderline, the deadlock disappers. Do you have any hint to understand where the deadlock come from?

========== UPDATE =======================

I logged the Spring/Hibernate logs here: https://codeshare.io/2j39mR
I logged the corresponding Mysql logs here: https://codeshare.io/GAk69x

Empirically I found out I've the deadlock when the `INSERT INTO AdjustmentOrderLine` is done in another Mysql thread than that of `insert into AdjustmentOrder` even if they are in the same transaction.

Comment: Is it really **single** AdjustmentOrderLine entry in transaction or deadlock happens only if multiple are inserted?

Comment: @Sankozi Just 1 adjustmentOrder + 1 AdjustmentOrderLine. For that reason I was surprised by the deadlock

Comment: Is `order_id` in step 2 always id from step 1? Are `store_id` in both steps always the same? Have you tried removing other foreign keys (alone)? It might be just that removing that FK reduces greatly chance of deadlock, by reducing transaction duration, but the cause is somewhere else.

Comment: @Sankozi Yes the order_id is the same from step1. Yes the store_id is the same in both steps. You mean try to remove all foreign keys from what table?

Comment: I was thinking about removing each FK constraint and checking what happens, but after you wrote that other FK are the same in both steps, I am out of ideas how two transactions like that can deadlock each other. Are you sure it is a deadlock between 2 transactions doing those 2 steps?

Comment: @Sankozi Removing the FKo4j5q73gdxcrrr9dg3t35mdq9 (order_id) on adjustmentorderline it works. But it seems very very odd. The only transactions involved are that and it seems confirmed from the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS